# Python array manipulation from psycopg2 PostgreSQL query

Tags: python, postgresql, list, psycopg2

I am using psycopg2 to do a psql query.

```
cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT name FROM product")
result = cur.fetchall()
print(result)

[('product1',), ('product2',), ('product3',), ('product4',)]
```

I need to reformat this array to make an API endpoint. Right now it is a list of tuples where the second value of the tuple is empty. A simple loop iterating through gets the job done.

```
results=[]
for item in result:
    results.append(item[0])
print(results)

['product1','product2','product3','product4']
```

However this query can get rather large. And iterating through the entire list adds a delay to the query that doesn't seem necessary. Is there a way to flatten the array in constant time, or a differnt psycopg2 function that returns in the format I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time needed to convert the list is negligible compared to the database query.
But you don't need to create a list first-hand:

```
cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT name FROM product")
result = [item for item, in cur]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate in the query:

```
query = '''
    select array_agg(distinct name)
    from product
'''
cursor.execute(query)
rs = cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
print rs
```

Output:

```
['product1', 'product2', 'product3', 'product4']
```